# Does the line in bold do the job?

Tags: sentence-choice

> Demonetization was supposed to at least partly solve the problem of
> black money in the economy. **It did very little of that** and only caused a lot of inconvenience to the common man.

I basically want to say that demonetization failed to achieve its objective. Does the above line in bold convey that message or is there a better way of saying it? I do not want to be so blunt to say point blank, "Demonetization failed."

Comment: The expression in bold works fine and the sentence is grammatical. In terms of style, depending on your intent, the word "only" might be problematic. It's unlikely that demonetization had *no other effect* besides causing inconvenience, and you can make the point that demonetization failed without asserting there were no other effects and nobody benefited in any way. Speaking so narrowly sounds biased and lowers your credibility. "Mostly" would work better and still achieve the desired effect, or just drop the word entirely.

Comment: In any remotely "formal" context, it would be far better to use ***intended*** rather than ***supposed***. There's little chance of "ambiguity" with Past Tense ***was supposed***, but it wouldn't be ridiculous to use Present Tense here (since the effects of demonetisation are still ongoing). And whereas there's only really one possible meaning to ***Demonetisation is intended to [achieve something]***, it's always possible that ***Demonetisation is supposed to [achieve something]*** might be understood as meaning that's what people currently ***think it does.***